# Preallocating List c#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am working in c# and I am creating a list (newList) that I can get from the length of another list (otherList). In c# is list implemented in a way that preallocating the length of the list is better for performance using otherList.Count or to just use newList.Add(obj) and not worry about the length?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following constructor for `List<T>` is implemented for the purpose of improving performance in scenarios like yours:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx

`public List(int capacity)`

Just pass the capacity in the constructor.

`newList = new List<string>(otherList.Count);`

Answer (score 4):

If you know the exact length of the new list, creating it with that capacity indeed performs - a bit - better.

The reason is that the implementation of `List<T>` internally uses an array. If this gets too small, a new array is created and the items from the old array are copied over to the new item.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the Remarks section on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx)

> The capacity of a `List<T>` is the number of elements that the `List<T>`
>   can hold. As elements are added to a `List<T>`, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array.
>
> If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while adding elements to the `List<T>`.
>
> The capacity can be decreased by calling the TrimExcess method or by
>   setting the Capacity property explicitly. Decreasing the capacity
>   reallocates memory and copies all the elements in the `List<T>`.

So, this would suggest that there would be a performance increase if you have an estimate of the size of the list you are going to populate. Of course the other-side of this is allocating a list size too big and therefore using up memory unnecessarily.

To be honest, I would not worry about this sort of micro optimization unless I really need to.

Answer (score 0):

So I benchmarked the scenario of preallocation, and just wanted to share some numbers. The code simply times this:

```
var repetitions = 100000000
var list = new List<object>();
for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
    list.Add(new object());
```

The comparison is by allocating in the list the exact number of repetitions, twice the number and without preallocation. This are the times:

- List not preallocated: 6561, 6394, 6556, 6283, 6466
- List preallocated: 5951, 6037, 5885, 6044, 5996
- List double preallocated: 6710, 6665, 6729, 6760, 6624

**So is preallocation worth it?** Yes if the number of objects in the list is known, or if a bottom line of this number is known (how many items will the list have at least).

If not, you could risk actually wasting more time and memory, since the preallocation will use time and memory to make space for the allocation desired.

Note that also in terms of memory, exact preallocation is the most memory efficient, since not preallocating will make your list grow over the tightest needed capacity.